# 3rd party C++ libs in RubyMotion

Tags: c++, objective-c, rubymotion

I'm trying to compile some 3rd party C++ libraries for iOS development with RubyMotion. I have an Objective-C wrapper around the libraries, in the form of .h and .mm files, but I have no idea what to do with them.

I'm assuming they go in my_app/vendor/my_lib/, but how do I tell RubyMotion about the files?

I've added the library to my project in my Rakefile:

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/my_lib', :static)
```

This picks up the .h/.a files. Will RubyMotion pick up .the mm (and corresponding .h) file as well, or do I need to flag this file as being a wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line to your Rakefile in the App.setup section like this:

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/my_lib', :static)
```

That will make the build process look in that directory for .h/.mm files to compile, as well as .a files to link into the app. There's a little more info [here](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_using_3rd_party_libraries).

Comment: I've edit my question to add what I have in my Rakefile. The RubyMotion docs mention using vendor_project() to add .h/.a files, but say nothing about also compiling .mm files.

Comment: I have a project here https://github.com/dpassage/ios-class/tree/master/TopPlaces in which I use `vendor_project` to compile some .m files into my app. Not sure if .mm makes a difference or not.